# Why do we have a conservation of probability during the transformation?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I don't know what it is called in the literature but whenever we have a transformation of random variables (x -> y) with the probability distributions of $g(y)\ 
\&\ f(x)$, we write saying that **probability is equal**, the following:

$$ f(x)dx = g(y)dy$$

Now, y and x are related through a function, let's take it to be $J(x) = y$. The next step is generally using the delta function for identifying the new probabilities $P(y)$ through $$ P(y) = \int dx\ \delta( y-J(x) ) f(x)  $$

Hence my two-part question:

How, starting from this, I can derive the first equation logically. The general derivation treats derivatives as fractions which I don't consider to be correct.

In some of the books, it is given directly. So, how does it make sense intuitively, too?

**Comment**

Since it is pointed out, the complete expression for P(y) would be

> $$ g(y)dy = P(y) = \int dx\ \delta( y-J(x) ) f(x)  $$

Comment: What do you call $P(y)$?  Is it a probability or a probability density?

Comment: The expression on RHS says that you have to sum all probabilities for the cases when x gives you y. This would give you the probability of y, not its density.

Comment: If the variable $y$ is continuous, the probability of $y$ is 0.

Comment: That actually doesn't matter. You can write the same expression with densities. But I don't know where are you going with this? It is not related to my question anyhow.

Comment: You say you don't consider treating derivatives as fractions correct. How do you make sense of the expressions like $f(x)dx$? Or even worse $P(y)=g(y)dy$? What is your definition of a derivative? In any case the derivation you seek is easily found online, eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190462/calculating-probability-from-closed-form-function/4193930#4193930)

Answer (score 1):

Your $P(y)$ is in reality $g(y)$ and the $dy$ in your last expression does not make sense. Here is an informal way to obtain $g$:  Let the random variable $X$ have density $f$ and suppose that $Y=J \circ X$ has density $g$.
Then given an interval (or Borel set) $A$ we have by definition of the densities that $$\int_A g(y) \; dy = P(Y\in A) = P(J\circ X \in A) = P(X\in J^{-1}(A))= \int_{J^{-1}(A)} f(x)dx$$
You may here introduce a factor of one, formally through a $\delta$-"function" integral and write the RHS as:
$$ \int_{J^{-1}(A)} \left( \int_{\Bbb R} \delta(y-J(x)) dy \right) f(x) \; dx =
\int_{J^{-1}(A)} \left( \int_{A} \delta(y-J(x)) dy \right) f(x) \; dx
.$$

Note that for every $x\in J^{-1}(A)$ we have $J(x)\in A$ so the inner integral equals one even when restricting the $y$-integral to $A$. Now, if you don't worry too much about Fubini when delta-functions are involved you get by interchanging integrals and then enlarging (without changing the values) the inner domain:
$$ \int_{A} \left( \int_{J^{-1}A } \delta(y-J(x)) f(x) \; dx \right) \; dy
= \int_{A} \left( \int_{{\Bbb R}} \delta(y-J(x)) f(x) \; dx \right)  \; dy
=: \int_A g(y) \; dy$$
thus identifying $g(y)$ with $\int_{\Bbb R} \delta(y-J(x)) f(x) dx$.
Assuming $J$ to be $C^1$, you can make this rigorous and get a formula for $g$
iff $J$ is regular almost surely on the values taken by $X$,
i.e. iff:
$$ P\left(X\in \{x\in {\Bbb R}: J'(x)\neq 0 \}\right)=1.$$
In a mathematical proof I would, however, rather avoid the delta function approach and use change of variables directly. But as I am not sure what you are after I stop here.